# What should i put into WebAPI controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can't find any information about types of operation, that i could extract into WebAPI controllers.

For example, we have two entities: `BusinessProcess` and `WorkItem`. Ofcourse, when we talk about displaying information (`return View()`) about this entities, i should create simple `Controller`, but i have methods like:

1. Save workitem information
2. Assign workitem to other user
3. Finish workitem
4. Change workitem expiration date
5. Stop/Start bussiness process

And with every of this methods i'm going to talk by `Ajax` from client side.

Should i put them into `Controllers`, or i could store there only `return View()` actions and extract `ajax conversation methods` into WebAPI?

By the way, i'll have more than one `Controller` (ManagerWorkItemController, EmployeeWorkItemController), but my upper methods (`Finish workitem` for example) will be common for them all.

Is it enought reason to create WebAPI?

Comment: There is no need to extract anything into WebApi controllers if you don't have the need to do so. If your existing code works and delivers the project then leave it at that and spend the time elsewhere. Ask yourself if there is any data that you wish to expose  directly (potentially to anyone who can see your URL) that will be consumed without using your existing Web UI? Is this now still as a "Must Have" or "nice to do"?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it would be neater to separate action calls from api calls.
A separate class would give you clarity about each class's responsibilities.
Still you can do both action and api calls in one controller, but it's up to you to decide how clear you want your code flow to be.
And it's better to have one api controller per data model. And check out the REST API pattern.